# How to speed up initial launch app of React native and Expo app

Tags: android, react-native, expo, splash-screen

I have created an app and added splach screen. It takes 1 second to load the app on Android Emulator. However after I publish the app in the store, it takes 4 seconds to load.

This is pretty annoying for such a simple app.

I was thinking it was because of _loadResourcesAsync func to load pictures. Therefore I commented out those lines but nothing has changed.

Any recommendation to speed up my app launch.

Here you can find my app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform, StatusBar, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { AppLoading, Asset } from 'expo';
import AppNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoadingComplete: false,
    };
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isLoadingComplete && !this.props.skipLoadingScreen) {
      return (
        <AppLoading
          startAsync={this._loadResourcesAsync}
          onError={this._handleLoadingError}
          onFinish={this._handleFinishLoading}
        />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
          <AppNavigator />
        </View>
      );
    }
  }

  _loadResourcesAsync = async () => {
    return Promise.all([
      Asset.loadAsync([
        // require('./assets/images/big_bottle.png'),
        // require('./assets/images/bottle.png'),
        // require('./assets/images/coffee.png'),
        // require('./assets/images/juice.png'),
        // require('./assets/images/menu.png'),
        // require('./assets/images/tea.png'),
        // require('./assets/images/water-glass.png'),
      ]),
    ]);
  };

  _handleLoadingError = error => {
    // In this case, you might want to report the error to your error
    // reporting service, for example Sentry
    console.warn(error);
  };

  _handleFinishLoading = () => {
    this.setState({ isLoadingComplete: true });
  };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});
```

Comment: Easiest way to speed it up is to use actual native code instead of React Native.  RN takes a long time to load.  Its a weakness of the platform.  It needs to drop into C and initialize a javascript interpreter, then load all of FB's code around that, then instantiate the initial view hierarchy.  That takes a while.

Comment: @GabeSechan thanks for your detailed answer. I am learning to code just for fun and I am in the beginning of learning process. I was thinking about to learn kotlin. Maybe I should start

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on my experience, hybrid apps, in general, tend to launch slower.

Based on my tests, even a completely blank Expo app, based on the device performance, can take anywhere from 1-4s to launch. This is the time it takes from the moment the user taps (opens) the app to the time the splash screen gets hidden (and the first app screen is visible).

What you can do to speed it up is a really broad topic. Here are two recommendations, that helped a lot for a project of mine:

1. Cashe your assets.

   [Bundling assets into your binary](https://docs.expo.io/guides/preloading-and-caching-assets/) will provide for the best user experience as your assets will be available immediately. Instead of having to make a network request to the CDN to fetch your published assets, your app will fetch them from the local disk resulting in a faster, more efficient loading experience.
2. Always load a cached version of your app first.

   You can configure the "updates" section in your app.json to always starts with the cached version of your app first (`fallbackToCacheTimeout: 0`) and continue trying to fetch the update in the background (at which point it will be saved into the cache for the next app load).

Unfortunately, as of today, it looks like we're kind of limited to what we can do to improve further the initial loading time on a blank app. There isn't really a reliable way to know how long the 'check for updates' process takes, the general React Native initialization time, the 'load all the JS' time.

There is a feature request for [tools for improving the startup time](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/tools-for-improving-startup-time), would be great if the Expo team introduces something similar anytime in the future.